# how to locate an element using UIAutomater when same thing is shared by two element

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

[image: in the attachment which i shared the camera picture and all photos have same resource-id class and everything then how to click on All photos, because if i am using anything always camera picture is getting clicked]

Both the Camera picture and All photos have same element locator then how can we click All pictures, i have explained everything in picture description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium interprets page as an XML, so there are no two elements with the same locator. So you can locate by the folder names for example.

`def cameraPicturesLocatorBy = By.xpath("//*[@text='Camera pictures']")`

and

`def allPhotosLocatorBy = By.xpath("//*[@text='All photos']")`

Comment: but the text value is not an identifier here...so i doubt it will work...but i will try using it

Comment: Identifier can be any property with distinct, unique value. Just look at the different properties of each element and find the one or a set that differs.

Comment: it worked thanks...but in the identifier list text value is empty...how it worked then?

Comment: If you look at the XML then it should be there.
Please mark my answer as the answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshots, you could use ids. in Python:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('your id')
```

Comment: but the camera picture and all photos both have same id, if i give the id everytime it is selecting camera picture